# Execute callback after asynchronous task in external script is completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to run javascript function after external asynchronous script was loaded?

After example.js runs (async. it seems), this is the result:

```
<div class="keepthisdiv">Keep this text</div>
<div class="removethisdiv">Remove this text</div>
<div class="keepthisdiv">Keep this text</div>
```

Example.js has to be run between body tags, if it's in the head, there is no output.

Here is my div container and js code ([credits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323723/how-to-run-a-javascript-function-after-a-specific-js-has-loaded)):

```
<div id="jscontainer"></div>

<script>

function loadBackupScript(callback){
    if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
       throw 'Not a valid callback';  
    }
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.onload = callback;  
    script.src = 'http://www.example.com/example.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    var container = document.getElementById("jscontainer");
    container.appendChild(script);
}

loadBackupScript(function() {

$( ".removethisdiv" ).remove();

});

</script>
```

However, it doesn't remove a div with `removethisdiv` class. `loadBackupScript` obviously runs before `example.js` is completely parsed.

How can I run `loadBackupScript` function right after `removethisdiv` class is inserted into DOM? I know that it is possible to use a timer and then remove it after few seconds, but it is unreliable, because external script's parsing times vary. Also, there are many different scripts on the same page, so I'd like to avoid waiting for page to load completely and I need to specifically target this script (example.js).

Comment: If example.js is yours - do it in there?

Comment: `loadBackupScript obviously runs before example.js is completely parsed` Why? it shouldn't be like this, load event is fired after the script is loaded and parsed.

Comment: @JayMee It's external script, I don't have any control over it.

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia I'm not an expert for js, but it certainly seems so. If I run it this way, it doesn't remove it. If I add a timer (e. g. 2 seconds) it removes it.

Comment: If the divs are created by your script, possibly asynchronously, that is a totally different story. The question is wrong, you can't show the divs in your html code if they are not actually there.

Comment: You are missing a very basic concept: *loaded* and *parsed* are not different in javascript. Once a script is *loaded* you are guaranteed it has also been *parsed* and *executed*, if then your script starts other async operations, that's another story.

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia I have edited the question to explain it better.

Comment: There is no magic bullet for this. You have to examine your external script, understand which async tasks is performing and execute your callback when they are completed. If you can't modify the external script, you could setup some polling with `setInterval` on variables or DOM elements the external script is going to change. Anyway why would you do this? Try to explain what you need to achieve and maybe we can suggest a more proper way of doing that.

Comment: Does `loadBackupScript` not work? Put a debugger in the callback or `console.log($( ".removethisdiv" ));`. It sounds like `example.js` might be asynchronously writing `removethisdiv` if the element doesn't exist.