# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined despite being able to see data on screen

Tags: javascript, html, csv, html-table, typeerror

I've got a table that is rendered by parsing data from a CSV file using js, I have copied code from W3schools to sort the table by clicking on the header that the user wants to be sorted. The code for this is in another js file which I link to right at the end to ensure the data is loaded but I still get this error. It occurs when I click on a column and references the first line in js with innerHTML.
This is the HTML followed by the js apologies for the bad formatting:

```
        {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block title %}POP | Omniscient {% endblock %}
    {% block css %}
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/CSS/pop.css">
    {% endblock %}
    
    {% block header %}
        <ul class="nav justify-content-end" id="nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('psychic') }}">Psychic</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('practical') }}">Practical</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    {% endblock %}
    
    
    {% block content %}
        <table id="main-table" class="table table-dark table-hover table-bordered border-white">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2"></th>
                    <th colspan="6" class="border-2">Threat</th>
                    <th colspan="4" class="border-2">Creativity</th>
                    <th colspan="2" class="border-2">FPL</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th onclick="sortTable(0)" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Cost">£M</th>
                    <th onclick="sortTable(1)" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Shots">S</th>
                    <th onclick="sortTable(2)" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Shots on target">OT</th>
                    <th onclick="sortTable(3)" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Shots in the box">In</th>
                    <th onclick="sortTable(4)" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Big Chances">BC</th>
                    <th onclick="sortTable(5)" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Expected Goals">xG</th>
                    <th onclick="sortTable(6)" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Goals">G</th>
                    <th onclick="sortTable(7)" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Key Passes">KP</th>
                    <th onclick="sortTable(8)" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Big Chances Created">BCC</th>
                    <th onclick="sortTable(9)" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Expected Assists">xA</th>
                    <th onclick="sortTable(10)" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Assists">A</th>
                    <th onclick="sortTable(11)" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Actual   Points">Points</th>
                    <th onclick="sortTable(12)" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Projected Points">Projected</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
    
    
        </table>
    
    
    
    
    
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="/static/Scripts/Navbar.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/Scripts/CSV-parse.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/Scripts/table-sort.js"></script>
    {%  endblock %}
```

```
    function sortTable(n) {
      var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
      table = document.getElementById("main-table");
      switching = true;
      // Set the sorting direction to ascending:
      dir = "asc";
      /* Make a loop that will continue until
      no switching has been done: */
      while (switching) {
        // Start by saying: no switching is done:
        switching = false;
        rows = table.rows;
        /* Loop through all table rows (except the
        first, which contains table headers): */
        for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
          // Start by saying there should be no switching:
          shouldSwitch = false;
          /* Get the two elements you want to compare,
          one from current row and one from the next: */
          x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
          y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
          /* Check if the two rows should switch place,
          based on the direction, asc or desc: */
          if (dir == "asc") {
            if (Number(x.innerHTML) > Number(y.innerHTML)) {
                shouldSwitch = true;
                break;
            }
          } else if (dir == "desc") {
                if (Number(x.innerHTML) < Number(y.innerHTML)) {
                    shouldSwitch = true;
                    break;
                }
          }
        }
        if (shouldSwitch) {
          /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch
          and mark that a switch has been done: */
          rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
          switching = true;
          // Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
          switchcount ++;
        } else {
          /* If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
          set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again. */
          if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
            dir = "desc";
            switching = true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Placing script at the end doesn't guarantee that it'll run after the DOM is fully built. If the problem is due to early loading you can try to use `defer` parameter. https://javascript.info/script-async-defer#defer

Comment: @RauboLuk defer is not working for me, you are right it was running before the DOM was built I used ```document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => alert("DOM ready after defer!"));``` but the alert comes up before the table is loaded so is the table not part of the DOM??

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` event doesn't wait for external resources like stylesheets etc. to load. There is also `load` event that you might check out. If that doesn't then there is similar problem to yours here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4323752